# Where do I go to run this code

Tags: android, mopub

I'm trying to integrate Mopub(Ad Network) to android studio and i'm told to run this code.

```
$MY_PROJECT_DIR $ mkdir mopub-sdk
$MY_PROJECT_DIR $ cp -R $MOPUB_DIR/mopub-android-sdk/mopub-sdk mopub-sdk
```

I have no idea where i'm suppose to put this. Can someone tell me?

Comment: They are asking to create a directory mopub-sdk inside your project directory, and copy there their SDK. You don't need to use shell commands for that, you can do this in file explorer.

Comment: I'm using android studio.

Comment: These commands, as I understand, are simply creating a folder in your project for the mopubSDK.  This can be done manually, this doesn't go in your project.

Comment: Do you know of any good tutorials on this subject?

Comment: open your OS command promt and type the commands. Make sure the directory is where your project is in.

Comment: MoPub is part of the Fabric suite from Twitter. It doesn't sound like you've signed up for Fabric. You should, then you can install their plugin into either Eclipse or Android Studio and add MoPub automatically (through the plugin) to your project. Don't bother to do it manually... ;-) Link to Fabric: http://fabric.io

Answer (score 0):

Signing up for Fabric isn't a requirement. It sounds like you're following instructions from https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/android/getting-started. Open Terminal, and execute the commands in your project directory:

`mkdir mopub-sdk`

`cp -R $MOPUB_DIR/mopub-android-sdk/mopub-sdk mopub-sdk`